# String substitution for object (non-dictionary)

Tags: python, string

Python has a great way to do string substitutions with a dictionary.
How can I replicate this same behaviour in my own object (rather than use a dictionary)?

```
In [1]: d = {'hello': 'world'}

In [2]: '%(hello)s' % d
Out[2]: 'world'
```

For example, if I have a class `MyClass`:

```
In [3]: class MyClass():
            a = 'x'
            b = 'y'

In [4]: m = MyClass()
```

*Without any mapping, we expect string substitution to throw an error (and they do), but suppose I want it to act like `{'a' : 'x'}` i.e. have the following return `'x'`:*

```
In [5]: '%(a)s' % m
TypeError: format requires a mapping
```

*I've been messing around with [format string syntax (`__format__`)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) or [template string](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings), without success.*

How can I provide my class a "mapping" (dictionary?) to use in string substitution?

Comment: What have you tried with `__format__`? You use that with the `''.format()` string method or the `format()` function, and what I'd advice you to use.

Comment: Also, I am assuming you ment to type `m = MyClass()` there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yep, thanks for spotting that typo! I'd tried adding it to MyClass as a dictionary, as I had seen this `__format__` in a library... I think I need to explore some other libraries (which have this feature) source codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `MyClass()` instances do have a dictionary associated with them, access it with the [`vars()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars):

```
'%(a)s' % vars(m)
```

This works for all custom classes that do not use a `__slots__` attribute.

Alternatively, you can use the newer [`''.format()` string formatting method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), which lets you access object attributes:

```
'{0.a}'.format(m)
```

It's this method of formatting that looks for a `.__format__(format_spec)` method on your custom classes, see the [`format()` function documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format).

Last but not least, any object with a [`.__getitem__()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) can be used for string formatting as if it is a dictionary:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __getitem__(self, name):
...         if name == 'bar': return 'baz'
...         raise AttributeError(name)
... 
>>> '%(bar)s' % Foo()
'baz'
```

Comment: unless the class has `__slots__`

Comment: Is it not possible to use the syntax `'%(a)s % m` ? This was the behaviour I was trying to emulate? I really want to be able to define this mapping myself (and not just have it be all the attributes)..

Comment: @AndyHayden: It is possible, sorry for not fully understanding your qusetion there. Amended to show how.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was missing! *Note: The reason I wanted to have the specific behaviour is to understand/fix this [regression/bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2814).*

Comment: Weirdly this seems to be in a situation where you can access `m['x']` (via `__getitem__`) but have this same error with `'%(x)s' % m` :s